# jest.fn() does not cover line of code written inside the mock function

Tags: angular, highcharts, jestjs

I have the following function and inside it a self invoke highcharts function.
I want to unit test this function with help of jest.fn() but it does not cover all lines mentioned inside the main function. Following is the actual funciton.

```
highChartsExtensionToReachZero() {
(function (H: any) {
  H.addEvent(H.Axis, 'afterInit', function () {
    const logarithmic = this.logarithmic;

    if (logarithmic && this.options.custom.allowNegativeLog) {

      // Avoid errors on negative numbers on a log axis
      this.positiveValuesOnly = false;

      // Override the converter functions
      logarithmic.log2lin = num => {
        const isNegative = num < 0;

        let adjustedNum = Math.abs(num);

        if (adjustedNum < 10) {
          adjustedNum += (10 - adjustedNum) / 10;
        }

        const result = Math.log(adjustedNum) / Math.LN10;
        return isNegative ? -result : result;
      };

      logarithmic.lin2log = num => {
        const isNegative = num < 0;

        let result = Math.pow(10, Math.abs(num));
        if (result < 10) {
          result = (10 * (result - 1)) / (10 - 1);
        }
        return isNegative ? -result : result;
      };
    }
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

}

The following is the jest code was written to mock and cover unit testing for the above code.

```
component.highChartsExtensionToReachZero = jest.fn();
component.highChartsExtensionToReachZero();
expect(component.highChartsExtensionToReachZero).toBeCalled();
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hi @Jeet, I'm not an expert in testing, but you probably don't need to wrap the plugin in IIFE, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0qerwsxu/ should be enough. You can also name your function, like: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dvb4sLrn/ but I don't know if it will help.